# How to make exact virtual machine from a system

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, backup

I have laptop `lenovo ideapad 310` in this laptop I have running windows 10 education edition and I want to make a Virtual Machine as backup of this system so I made backup of disk by Acronis True Image and restored in to a VM but application on run time asks to give permission to check Hardware. this mean Application is working With cheeking CPU ID and other device ID's how can I solve this situation.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Acronis really creates a vhd or vhdx file, but you need this format. My recommendation is to use [disk2vhd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) which is free and supported by MS. Finally you can import the vhdx file into Hyper-V as a new computer.